# @Html.RenderPartial replace the the main view window with partial view content only instead of it displaying partial view inside the mainview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, master-detail, asp.net-mvc-partialview

The issue is that when I try to render a Partial View Inside the Main View, it replace the the main view window with partial view content only instead of it displaying partial view inside the mainview

### SearchForm.html

```
@model IEnumerable<MobileFirmDirectory.Models.User>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResultsPar", "User", FormMethod.Post))
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchResultsPar", 
                       new AjaxOptions 
                       {
                           UpdateTargetId = "SearchResults",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                           HttpMethod="GET"
                       })) 
{
    <fieldset><legend>Firm Directory Search:</legend>
      <div style="float:left;margin:10px;">
        <table style="padding:20px 0px 0px 20px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;" >Last Name:</td>
            <td style="width:300px">@Html.TextBox("lname")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">First Name:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("fname")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">Title Name:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("titletext")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt;">Office:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Office", ViewBag.officeList as SelectList, "Select Office") </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <table style="float: right;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="return submitcheck();" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id="SearchResults" style="float:right;margin:10px;padding:10px;border:dotted 5px black;">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultsPartial");}
      </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

### Controller Action

```
public ActionResult SearchResultsPar(string lname, string fname, string titletext, string office)
{
    **Code is hidden intentionally**
    return PartialView("SearchResultsPartial",obj);
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use RenderPartial with a child action?

Comment: Yes. Its kind of a master/detail page.

Comment: I don't think RenderPartial uses a child action. That's not exactly your issue, but RenderAction uses a child action. Please check your design.

Comment: Dave, I am not sure what is child action means. Basically what I am trying to do is: The main view is a search form where user fill out bunch of search criteria field and hit the submit button that is taken care by controller's "SearchResult" ActionResult and returns a partial view as PartialView("SearchResultsPartial",obj). As a result I wanted to display the returned search results on the bottom of the search form itself as a partial view and if you see my code for that I am using  <div id="SearchResults" >
        @{Html.RenderPartial("SearchResultsPartial");}
      </div>

Comment: I was pointing out that Html.RenderPartial does not call your action method. it simply renders your partial without making the call to your action method.

Comment: Dave, Thats true I simply wanted to render the partial view in my main view without calling any action method since action method called by the form submit already filled out that partial view data. The issue is, it renders the partial view but not as partial but in its own window. Here is my BeginForm code: @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchResultsPar", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "SearchResults", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod="GET" }))

Comment: does the problem occur when the page is first rendered or after you submit your ajax form?

Comment: The problem occurs after I submit the form. It should bring my results to the host page in the form of a partial view instead of opening the partial view in it's own window.

Comment: did u truly comment out the html.beginform? i only see a close comment, not open. plz confirm...

Comment: Sorry, That was by mistake here in stackoverflow editor. I fixed it here but it was already good in my MVC project so that wasn't an issue.

Comment: Got it. I'm bothered by similarity in name between partial view and action method. This usually causes a child-method relationship. I know it's a stretch, but try re-naming one so their names are different.

Comment: They are different ActionMethod is "SearchResultsPar" and the PartialView is "SearchResultsPartial"

Comment: Wow... stuck like shoe on gum

Comment: Ya it sucks ...Also I am noticing a weired behaviour when I hit the submit button, it try to load the ActionResult View Page ("http://localhost:port/user/SearchResultsPar" - even though there is no such page exists) and when I hit the back button on browser, it shows me partialview (SearchResultsPartial) under my host page. I am not sure why is it going that far and loading the SearchResultPar.

Comment: Ok finally figured it out. This was due to a css file   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" /> If I remove this reference from main view everything works but the issue is that I can't go without that Css that we using to render mobile version of our app.

Comment: good find. post your answer.

Comment: make rendering the view conditional on ViewBag value passed to View. Check it in your layout